# Possibility of speeding up transitive closure list updater

Tags: r, list, graph-theory, igraph, transitive-closure

I have created the following function:

```r
update_list3 = function(identity_dict){
    suppressMessages(suppressWarnings({
        library(ggm)
        #adjacency matrix
        g = matrix(unlist(lapply(identity_dict, FUN = function(x){
            b = rep(0, length(identity_dict))
            b[x] = 1
            b})),
            nrow = length(identity_dict), byrow = T)
        #map transitive closure
        closure = transClos(g)
        #turn back to adjacency list
        out_list = lapply(as.list(data.frame(t(closure))), FUN = function(x){which(x == 1)})
        #tranclos removes self-connection, so bind self back to own identity
        out_list = mapply(c, as.list(c(1:length(out_list))), out_list, SIMPLIFY = F)
        lapply(out_list, FUN = sort)
    }))
}
```

To update a list, identity_dict, of the form:

```
1: {1,3,4}
2: {2,5}
3: {3,4}
4: {4}
5: {5}
```

to provide the transitive closure of the undirected graph, with the form:

```
1: {1,3,4}
2: {2,5}
3: {1,3,4}
4: {1,3,4}
5: {2,5}
```

This works for small problems, but larger problems begin to stall quite quickly. Would there be a possibility of performing the same calculation by different means - perhaps the matrix transformation is limiting due to size?

*An ideal solution would **not use iGraph**, as we have had problems with this package returning errors for large problems.*

Inputs work as intended, but speed rapidly decreases with large problems.

Does not scale to larger problems in good time.

Comment: I would like to respond to _"An ideal solution would not use iGraph, as we have had problems with this package returning errors for large problems."_ Keep in mind that igraph is the work of volunteers _like you_ who offered their free time to create and maintain this open-source package. _You_ can contribute too, for example by reporting any problems you encounter, so that they can be fixed.

Comment: You say you want _"to provide the transitive closure of the undirected graph"_. Transitive closure is not a useful concept for _undirected_ graphs. It is simply a disjoint union of complete graphs on each connected component. Consider if this is really what you want to compute.

Comment: @Szabolcs regarding your first comment, I completely understand and, when I am able to trace the exact error my iGraph implementation returns, one of my first aims is to get this communicated as a potential bug. regarding your second comment, the goal of this tool is to attempt to link several unlinked trees - one of the steps is therefore "establishing a link" and cascading any relationships throughout the whole, newly linked component. I realise it's a potentially unusual application, but it does work well for our means. thanks for your advice :)

Comment: I don't quite understand your description, but I assume you just want a quick way to check if two vertices are within the same connected component? This is precisely what "transitive closure" is for an undirected graph. Then simply compute connected components. `c <- components(g)`. If `c$membership[v] == c$membership[u]` then `v` and `u` are in the same component. _Do not construct the transitive closure for this!_ It will have a quadratic number of edges and it will be impossible to store for large graphs.

Answer (score 1):

- If you would like to ***avoid*** using `igraph`, you can use the following code

```
dict <- identity_dict
out <- list()
repeat {
    if (length(dict) == 0) {
        break
    }
    d <- as.character(dict[[1]])
    repeat {
        d2 <- dict[as.character(unique(unlist(d)))]
        v <- as.character(unique(unlist(d2)))
        if (length(setdiff(v, d)) == 0) {
            dict <- dict[!names(dict) %in% v]
            out[v] <- rep(list(as.integer(v)), length(v))
            break
        } else {
            d <- v
        }
    }
}
identity_dict <- out[names(identity_dict)]
```

which finally gives

```
> identity_dict
$`1`
[1] 1 3 4

$`2`
[1] 2 5

$`3`
[1] 1 3 4

$`4`
[1] 1 3 4

$`5`
[1] 2 5
```

---

- If `igraph` works for you (I have no clue what kind of errors you have encountered with `igraph`), I think `components` and `membership` is the thing you may need, e.g.,

```
# group info
grp <- stack(identity_dict) %>%
    graph_from_data_frame() %>%
    components() %>%
    membership()

# update `identity_dict`
identity_dict[] <- ave(
    as.integer(names(grp)),
    grp,
    FUN = list
)[match(names(identity_dict), names(grp))]
```

such that

```
> identity_dict
$`1`
[1] 1 3 4

$`2`
[1] 2 5

$`3`
[1] 1 3 4

$`4`
[1] 1 3 4

$`5`
[1] 2 5
```

## Data

```
identity_dict <- list(
    `1` = c(1, 3, 4),
    `2` = c(2, 5),
    `3` = c(3, 4),
    `4` = 4,
    `5` = 5
)
```

and

```
> identity_dict
$`1`
[1] 1 3 4

$`2`
[1] 2 5

$`3`
[1] 1 3 4

$`4`
[1] 1 3 4

$`5`
[1] 2 5
```